# Microsoft graph API: query to list all users with NO group membership

Tags: filter, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a Microsoft graph API query that will list all our users with NO group membership.

I can get all the users with

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users
```

loop over them and evaluate the groups they are members of

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{}/memberOf
```

and return the ones with zero group memberships. We have a large number of users so this takes time. Quicker to ask the API to return the list I want the first time.

Can I, in one query, filter on just the users that are in no groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Just try the query below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select = userPrincipalName,displayname&$expand=memberof
```

With this query, you will be able to get a list that contains user data you selected with group membership data just as below:

[image]

So that you could filter users you want locally instead of calling APIs 1 by 1.

Comment: Hi @Anthony,Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )